# Insert tags in text after deleting characters using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, filtering

I need to tag text in raw source column which matches text in another column where the same info was extracted by human. The raw column is unfiltered and methods like .find() and regex maching works only if I delete certain characters or regex phrases. The problem is I can't really keep track of how many characters I deleted to put tag in correct place in original text.

I did something like this to know positions of deleted characters:

```
def delete_characters(text, characters):
    # Find positions of characters-to-delete and delete them (positions are needed to compute shift)
    rx = '[' + re.escape(''.join(characters)) + ']'
    deleted_positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(rx, text)]     
    return re.sub(rx, '', text) , deleted_positions #remove the list of chars defined above
```

Then if I match something after filtering I tag with: (where position is the place where match was found)

```
def insert_tag(cls, text, position, deleted_positions , to_print):
            shift_l = sum(1 for i in deleted_positions if i < position[0])
            shift_r = sum(1 for i in deleted_positions if i < position[1])
            begin_tag = f"[{cls.tag_name}]"
            end_tag = f"[/{cls.tag_name}]"
            start_pos = position[0] + shift_l
            end_pos = position[1] + shift_r
            text = text[:start_pos] + begin_tag + text[start_pos:end_pos] + end_tag + text[end_pos:]
            return text, str(start_pos)
```

This seems to work with single characters, but if I want to filter regex like \s the tags end up in wrong places.

Comment: Is [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) what you want?

Comment: I use re.sub to filter characters to enable matching query patterns, If my raw column is: "This is text 1. This is \r\n text,  2. This is ,text 3 ."  And my query column is "This is text 3" I need to end up with "This is text 1. This is \r\n text,  2. [tag]This is ,text 3 .[/tag]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()` by replacing space in query string with `[\W_]+`.

```py
import re

text="""This is text 1. This is 
 text, 2. This is ,text_3 ."""

query_string="This is text 3"

print(re.sub("("+query_string.replace(" ","[\W_]+")+"[\W_]+)",r"[tag]\1[/tag]",text))
```

**Output**

```
This is text 1. This is
 text, 2. [tag]This is ,text_3 .[/tag]
```